# How can I remove digits after decimal in axis ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have

```
tick_location = np.linspace(0.01, 10, num=10, endpoint=True)
ax2.set_xticks(tick_location)
tick_labels = np.around(1/new_tick_loc*1e4,decimals=-2)
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_labels)
```

This (and some additional code) produces the following plot, but I'd like to remove the decimal point and the digit after it from the tick labels on the top x axis.

Using [matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter) does not help

[image: top x axis with decimal]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert the numbers into ints:

```
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_labels.astype(int))
```

Comment: I've been trying to typecast but I get the following error, including with your suggestion: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'. I found a roundabout answer, but IT WORKS, posted below.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. Changed the location of the parenthesis.

Comment: Great - thanks!  One can also skip the 'np.' and simply go with 'int'.  This is simpler than my solution below.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Improved.

Comment: You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Is there some easy way to do this, it takes a lot of time when data Is huge,

Comment: i have 20000 rows approx and doing this consumes a lot of time

Comment: please update if any!!!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the labels in yticks `.astype(int)` worked for me on the y-axis (xticks for the x-axis):

```
plt.yticks(ticks=plt.yticks()[0], labels=plt.yticks()[0].astype(int))
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to tend to find an answer soon after I post my own question. It's not very straightforward but it works.  Simply insert four lines casting the tick numbers into strings and remove manually the decimal and everything after it:

```
tick_location = np.linspace(0.01, 10, num=10, endpoint=True)
ax2.set_xticks(tick_location)
tick_labels = np.around(1/new_tick_loc*1e4,decimals=-2)
tick_labels_str = tick_labels.astype(str)
tick_labels_free=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    tick_labels_free.append(tick_labels_str[i].split('.')[0])
ax2.set_xticklabels(tick_labels_free)
```

The '10' in 'range(0,10)' gives the last tick at 1000 even if it is not reflected in the image below. The '[0]' takes the first part of the string which has now been split - for me the part without decimals.  And the desired tick labels:

[image: correct top x axis]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but if you have your data in a dataframe, then this works:

```
df.columns = pd.to_numeric(df.columns, downcast='integer')
```